# status code 400 with no error object when uploading to box

Tags: node.js, post, request, box

I'm trying to use the `request.js`library to upload a file to box.com using request.post.

I consistently get a return code of 400 and a null body in the response. Not sure how to get at the actual error that box is seeing. The `err` argument to the callback is null, so there is a response from box.com, but with a statuscode of 400 and a null body.

FYI, the upload succeeds using curl, so the auth token etc. is fine.
I pointed the function below to http://echo.200please.com', and it seems the HTTP POST request I'm sending out is fine.
How do I get to see what error is being seen by box?

```
request = require"request");
UploadFile = function(filename, callback) {
    var formData = {
        attributes: JSON.stringify( {
            name: filename, 
            parent: { id: '' + 2764913765 }
        }),
        file: fs.createReadStream('./temp.bin')
    }
    var options = {
        url: 'https://upload.box.com/api/2.0/files.content', 
        headers: { Authorization: 'Bearer ' + tokens.access_token},
        formData: formData
    }

    request.post(options,
                 function(err, response, body) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('Error Uploading the file');
        } else {
            console.log('returned:' + body + JSON.stringify(response.headers))
        }
    });
```

If I change the URL to point to echo.200please.com, the response I get from echo.200please.com is below, which seems to be the correct format for a file upload request.

```
> POST / HTTP/1.0
Host: echo.200please.com
Connection: close
Content-Length: 1951
Authorization: Bearer bVPDzG8PgIVRNoqb5LOzD61h6NXhJ6h0
content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------------799592280904953105406767

----------------------------799592280904953105406767
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="attributes"

{"name":"testchunkname.1","parent":{"id":"2764913765"}}
----------------------------799592280904953105406767
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="temp.bin"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

<... file data ...>
```

Comment: Does it make any difference if you buffer up the file instead of streaming it?

Comment: tried that.. makes no difference. If I send an equivalent curl request from the command line, it succeeds. I did notice that if I put in a wrong auth token in the curl command as well, it fails silently, which led me to think my javascript request command is failing authentication. However, I just cannot figure out why it would fail, give that my get request are all succeeding with the same auth token and same javascript request code.

Answer (score 0):

OK ... I found the bug :-)
It's a typo in the url
in my program it got set to `api/2.0/files.content` whereas the correct path in the url should be `api/2.0/files/content`